# How to call for an custom attribute in magento backend order page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, sales-order, backend

I have magento 1.9 and at the order page ( /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml ) I need to add a custom attribute called "location"

```
<?php if ($_item = $this->getItem()): ?>
<h5 class="title"><span id="order_item_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>_title"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></span></h5>
<div><strong><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('SKU') ?>:</strong> <?php echo implode('<br />', Mage::helper('catalog')->splitSku($this->escapeHtml($this->getSku()))); ?></div>
<h5 class="title"><span id="order_item_location__title">Locatie: <?php echo implode('<br />', Mage::helper('catalog')->splitSku($this->escapeHtml($this->getLocation()))); ?></span></h5>
```

I'm not so good with magentoI have tried to mix codes I've found from blogs but still won't be able to get the value of "location".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an attribute called "location" active,
place below code anywhere you like in sales/items/column/name.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getProduct()->getLocation()); ?>
```

If "location" is a dropdown or multiselect value, use this instead

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('location')); ?>
```